# Seed up refresh of large raster layer in QGIS

Tags: gis, raster, qgis

I am a novice `QGis` user, and I’m sure there is an easy way to do what I want, but I don’t have a clue as how to start.  I downloaded a bunch of SRTM DEM sections and combined them into one raster layer.  An image of my elevations and rivers is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMpjk.png).

The problem is that the area covered is all of eastern Europe, so it takes a long time to refresh whenever I pan around the map.  Is there a way to speed this up?

I suppose that things would go faster had I not combined all the sections into one raster, but I want all the sections to have the same properties, and don’t want to have to change the properties for each segment one-at-a-time every time I change properties.

If someone could point me in the right direction on this that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you can do to increase your rendering performance, most of them under `Settings -> Options -> Rendering`:

[image: QGis Settings Options]

You could use **render caching** to allow QGis to spare some computations when redrawing your rasters. You can also check **render layers in parallel** by using CPU cores to give the rendering more resources, as well as **enable feature simplification** for new layers. You can also *uncheck* the **less jagged lines** option to prevent the use of that extra performance it takes.

Another trick I usually do when moving around large maps and rasters is to **uncheck** the *render* option, **move and pan** around, and then **check** the *render* option back again on the desired region. This I found prevents unnecessary rendering when moving, panning and zooming repeated times. This is the render feature I was mentioning, you can find it in your bottom bar:

[image]

You can also check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210723/qgis-rendering-performance-bottleneck) related GIS Stackexchange question if you want to know more options.

Hope this helps.